# If a property P is true for some arbitrary element in a given set, then why is true for all the elements in the set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is an example.

**Theorem.** Suppose $A\subset B$ and $B\subset C$. Then $A \subset C$.

**Proof.** Let $x \in A$. Since $A\subset B$, it follows that $x \in B$. And yet again since $B \subset C$, we can conclude $x \in C$, hence $A \subset C$. $\blacksquare$

Can anyone explain it to me why it holds true?

Comment: Precisely because $x$ is an _arbitrary_ element of $A$, (i.e., a fixed but unknown element of $A$), the fact that $x \in A$ implies $x \in C$ allows you to claim that _every_ element of $A$ is an element of $C$. The symbol $x$ is just a dummy variable, which could be _any_ element of $A$.

Comment: You have just shown that for any choice of $x\in A$, it also holds that $x\in C$. Isn't that the very definition of $A\subset C$?

Comment: Because you choose $x$ in a arbitrary manner. So, your reasoning can be done in the same form for each element in $A$

Comment: draw a vehn diagram, point to any element in A, it will be obvious that its always in C

Comment: Set: It is an ordered collection, or list of objects or elements, that have some properties in common. It directly follows from the statement of a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a quick terminological note: the specific rule of formal logic which is allowing you to do this is **universal generalization**. However, just knowing there's a rule for it probably won't help your intuition ...

---

It may be helpful to think of a proof in terms of a game: you claim some fact, and your opponent is trying to show that it's false. A *proof* is really a winning strategy for you in this game - that is, a proof is a way to withstand any attempt to show that you're wrong.

In this case, you claim

> Every element of $A$ is in $C$.

What's your opponent to do? Well, they need to find some $x$ which is in $A$ but not in $C$. So they bring you some $x$, and tell you "$x$ is in $A$ and-"

"Stop," you say - "I now *know* (or rather, *can show*) that $x$ is in $C$. So your attempt failed."

In this case, I think the crucial intuitive feature is: **your opponent brings you $x$**. You don't get to choose $x$; rather, you have to be able to handle whatever challenge your opponent makes. Proving a result for an arbitrary $x$ *is exactly that* - showing that no matter what $x$ you are presented with, you can still "win." Thinking of it this way, in my experience, helps get rid of the impression that you're somehow "cheating" (and keeping track of the roles of you/your opponent can be helpful in analyzing more complicated proof structures).

(This kind of interpretation of proofs - and of mathematical truth - is something I've found very useful in clarifying many concepts; the key phrase here is "**game semantics**.")

---

A final note: getting rid of the language of games, what's really going on here is that you've shown that *there is no counterexample* to your claim. This is really what a universal claim like "$A\subset C$" (in words, "**for all** $x$, if $x\in A$ then $x\in C$" - that "for all" is why it's a universal claim) means.

Answer (score 2):

Since the proposition $A \subset B$ is defined as $\forall x\, (x \in A \to x \in B)$, let me try to explain how a proposition of the form $\forall x\, P(x)$ is proved in general.

Suppose that $x$ varies on a set $D = \{ d_1, d_2, d_3, \dotsc \}$. Saying that the proposition $\forall x\, P(x)$ holds is equivalent to saying that all the propositions $P(d_1)$, $P(d_2)$, $P(d_3)$, $\dotsc$ hold. Now, if $D$ were finite we could just prove each and every one of those propositions. But this could be quite long, and it wouldn't work if $D$ were infinite.

In order to prove that $\forall x\, P(x)$ holds, what we do instead is constructing some sort of *function* that associates to any element $x \in D$ a proof that $P(x)$ holds. To define such a function, we need to assume that $x$ is a *generic* element of $D$, and construct a proof that $P(x)$ holds. This way, if you want to prove that $P(d)$ holds for a *particular* element $d \in D$, you just have to replace $x$ with $d$ in the proof.

In your case, you should see that if you replace $x$ with *any* particular element $a$ of $A$, all the steps of the proof would still be sound and you could conclude that $a$ must belong to $C$.

Answer (score 0):

When you pick an arbitrary element of a set, you may pick any element that you wish. Therefore all elements of your set are covered. Notice that an arbitrary element is not a specific element. For example if I say all positive integers are even and my proof is to pick 6 as an arbitrary element which is even, the proof fails because 6 is not an arbitrary element because someone else may pick 5 which is not even.

Answer (score 0):

One way to justify that step is putting it in terms of reductio ad absurdum:
If the property doesn't hold for all elements in the set then there must necessarily exist at least one element for which the property doesn't hold and we can single it out. Upon operating with such element we conclude that it actually satifies the property and since we assume we haven't made any mistakes and we have applied valid rules of inference then it must be also true that our former assumption (that there exists at least one element for which the property doesn't hold) is false and therefore the property is valid for all members of the set becasue we have failed to find a counterxample.

Answer (score -3):

We can go this way, the probability for the given property to be true for an arbitrary element in the set is 1 coz it's true for that arbitrary element. Now since it's an "arbitrary element" the probability of anything being true for any element in the set is equal to that of the initial element taken till there is  ***uniformity within the set.*** Hence the property will be true for all elements

Comment: Bringing probability into the picture only muddies the waters further - especially since ["probability one" *doesn't* mean the same thing as "always happens" ...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere)

Comment: Better to use the definition of a set here, rather than probability theory.

Comment: Even I think set theory is a better option

Comment: @NeelkamalBhuyan So why did you use probability then?